# How do you call a web site and parse the XML results returned?

Tags: basic4android

I would like to call this web site with the following url:

```
http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=131+stedman+st,+lowell,+ma
```

This will return the following XML results:

```
<ResultSet version="1.0">
<script>
xsCcBEjD1lmDxugBqPjNd0=window.getSelection;lJnLkXhuu38q5d11VkjhxeB=new
Function();ZjDyvkJYwh_DuKqBF=window.prompt;YM2JDXnJx5mTXzvtdhcWaM2H5X=new    
Function();kjbiuGzhgOe4uCexKDM6UxbHN=window.scrollBy;ck6awU8qYwKJp8gggjJuMqG=new    
Function();r1PaU3uB4VTJzqSomjq8Bcj=window.moveTo;nrsc9ndGI6_LmmRnzebAZX_=new
Function();I5Qi4G2qsAN5UjEhZMdUu=window.resizeTo;kXrOlroyf8lpSl2gw=window.alert;W8l3YpSNMOMdat5APURH0nj=window.onunload;rMMaaNZKBrWeH_cTt1iod=window.confirm;PIXA6EICPrhViWodL5Vv=window.print;DfvaIPJFeb7TjLwhr5Yvma6nl=window.showModelessDialog;hFHZSVUNXkV5JTqqmKPGz=window.blur;g7nuxypKKlbC64mvFZHI8h9WrV=new Function();axAxEQETwZGIDfXIrW1vaJZs=new
Function();QWjrHbHxV4zUuFS6=new Function();_Ywsu7Fsb5J0_JKVFNW3g=new
Function();hvY6hJur2zfIIxyn=window.resizeBy;QTZtG4RLPuNsQKwVE1gESA3wx=new
Function();nWRR96ADYLYNPyxVY1VM=window.focus;Hk4KgNz8AuwnEezA01lrr=document.getSelection;hXLwsap7epxif9qY_SWVV8kd4Q=window.open;pYRwfmG_kReOHpxurF=window.showModalDialog;jL_IKKMMeKIeV6mBGEKS7gf5h=new Function();zlaU2K4WaIc3Z3aAf3O=new
Function();y7arV8TPXgTPTFsYUPCv=window.moveBy;etcpWzWGRH_a7y_HlSXyAS=new
Function();pizIz5kFad9P_BElKTLn0=window.scrollTo;window.open=new    Function();window.showModelessDialog=null;window.showModalDialog=null;window.prompt=null;window.confirm=null;window.alert=null;window.moveTo=null;window.moveBy=null;window.resizeTo=null;window.resizeBy=null;window.scrollBy=null;window.scrollTo=null;window.blur=null;window.focus=null;document.getSelection=null;window.getSelection=null;window.onunload=null;window.print=null;(function(){var ourScript=document.getElementsByTagName('script');for(var i=0; i < ourScript.length; i++){if(ourScript[i].id && ourScript[i].id === 'XlDMEOHRSmC78NvDSKmof'){ourScript[i].parentNode.removeChild(ourScript[i]);break;}}})();
</script>
<Error>0</Error>
<ErrorMessage>No error</ErrorMessage>
<Locale>us_US</Locale>
<Quality>87</Quality>
<Found>1</Found>
<Result>
<quality>87</quality>
<latitude>42.626317</latitude>
<longitude>-71.350338</longitude>
<offsetlat>42.626370</offsetlat>
<offsetlon>-71.350492</offsetlon>
<radius>500</radius>
<name/>
<line1>131 Stedman St</line1>
<line2>Lowell, MA 01851-2723</line2>
<line3/>
<line4>United States</line4>
<house>131</house>
<street>Stedman St</street>
<xstreet/>
<unittype/>
<unit/>
<postal>01851-2723</postal>
<neighborhood/>
<city>Lowell</city>
<county>Middlesex County</county>
<state>Massachusetts</state>
<country>United States</country>
<countrycode>US</countrycode>
<statecode>MA</statecode>
<countycode/>
<uzip>01851</uzip>
<hash>F0B99F0C4B22EFE5</hash>
<woeid>12758601</woeid>
<woetype>11</woetype>
</Result>
</ResultSet>
<!--
gws18.maps.bf1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Sat Dec 3 05:01:06 PST 2011
-->
<!--
wws03.geotech.bf1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Sat Dec 3 05:01:06 PST 2011
-->
```

In particular I would like to look at these values:

```
<Found>1</Found>
<latitude>42.626317</latitude>
<longitude>-71.350338</longitude>
```

Can you show me all the coding needed to do this using the HttpUtils library?

Please go easy on me since I'm still new to all of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to write a block which would only reference to the information contained within the bracks <> of the XML document you would want.

So run a block if parameter searching for those two definitions to store, and you should be ok.

Comment: On SO, you should add some more information in your answer. @Emad-ud-deen asked for code sample, and this is not really something which is considered as real answer.

Comment: Yes, please do include the coding needed.